# animation: how to animate a view using layer?

Tags: ios, core-animation

[Image showing what I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrsyl.png)

I want to move a view animately from a position to a new postion. If update the layer position of a view, I think the view will animately  move to the new position, which is `implicit animation` I guess, but there's no animation, why?

```
- (IBAction)startAnimation:(id)sender {
    CGPoint position = self.imageView.layer.position;
    position.y += 90;
    self.imageView.layer.position = position;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implicit animations only happen for standalone layer, not layers backing up views. You will need to explicitly animate the position. You can either do it by creating a CABasicAnimation for the position and add it to the layer or use UIView animations to animate the center property of the view.

### Creating an explicit animation

```
CABasicAnimation *move = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
move.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:newPoint];
move.duration = 0.3;
[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:move forKey:@"myMoveAnimation"];
```

### Using UIView animations

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.imageView.center = newCenter;
}];
```

Comment: Or a third option would be to create an additional layer and add as a sublayer of the view's layer, and then change the properties of that additional layer. That way the additional layer won't be a view backing layer, and it will support implicit animation. However, UIView animation is much, much easier and cleanerthan creating CAAnimation objects

Comment: David, I'm having troubles with the `toValue` property while moving a layer to a new position. Would you mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554068/is-cabasicanimations-tovalue-relative-to-initial-position