# Is CABasicAnimation's toValue relative to initial position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I have a `CALayer` that I'm explicitly animating to a new position. My `toValue` property seems only relative to the layer's initial position.

```
    CABasicAnimation *move = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    move.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(blueDot.position.x, blueDot.position.y)];
    move.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y)];
    move.duration = 1.0;
    [blueDot addAnimation:move forKey:@"myMoveAnimation"];
    blueDot.position = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y);
```

So this code isn't redrawing the layer to the view's center. It seems as if it's really redrawing the layer to `CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + blueDot.position.x, self.view.center.y + blueDot.position.y)`, like it's adding the `float` values of `self.view.center` to the layer's starting position.

Is the `toValue` property supposed to act like this? What's the cleanest way to move my `blueDot` to the center of the view?

---

EDIT:

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        blueDot = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        [blueDot setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 60 - 5, 163.5, 10, 10)] CGPath]];
        [blueDot setStrokeColor: [UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
        [blueDot setFillColor:[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
        [[self.view layer] addSublayer:blueDot];
    }

// 163.5 is a placeholder for another view's position value so it's more readable for you guys.
```

Comment: There is a CAPropertyAnimation property to control this called `additive`. If you're not changing it, then it should be off by default.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not setting the `additive` property.

Comment: Also, it seems like this could all be done using implicit animations, if you just want the position to change.

Comment: Implicit animation doesn't seem to work for me. I'm calling `blueDot.position = CGPointMake(x,y)` inside `[UIView animateWithDuration:]`, and the blueDot just seems to jump there. Explicit animation animates properly, albeit to the wrong position.

Comment: @dperk That's not how you do an layer implicit animation – that's for `UIView` animations. You want to do your implicit animation inside a `CATransaction` block. i.e `[CATransaction begin]; [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:1.0]; <your changes to the layer> [CATransaction commit];`

Comment: @originaluser2, for layer properties that support implicit animation you don't need the CATransaction begin/end at all. You just change the property and the change is animated with default settings. The CATransaction calls are only needed if you need to change the default animation settings (easing, duration, etc.)

Comment: Implicit animation only works with LAYER properties, not view properties. That's the key thing.

Comment: @DuncanC Sure sure you don't need the `CATransaction` if you're happy with the default settings, I was just translating OP's explicit animation into an implicit one :)

Comment: @dperk That's for layer backed *views*. Your `blueDot` isn't an underlying layer of a given view – it's just a layer. Therefore you cannot use `[UIView animateWithDuration:]` on it.

Comment: For what I'm trying to achieve, I'm just going to use a `UIView` instead of a `CAShapeLayer`. It's easier to implicitly animate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you're moving the `frame` of the layer, but the blue dot `path` of this `CAShapeLayer` has been offset within that layer's `frame` by `self.view.center.x - 60 - 5, 163.5`, the coordinates you specified when creating the `path` for that `CAShapeLayer`. So when you animate the `position` of the layer, the blue dot will still be offset by that amount from this new `position`.

The fix is to define the `path` of the `CAShapeLayer` to be in the upper left corner of the layer, e.g.

```
CAShapeLayer *blueDot = [CAShapeLayer layer];
blueDot.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(5, 5) radius:5 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI * 2 clockwise:true].CGPath;  // note that using arc often generates a better looking circle, probably not noticeable at this size, just probably good practice
blueDot.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
```

Now when you move the `position`, that's where the blue dot's origin will move.

---

As an aside, I'd generally create a separate `UIView` and add this `CAShapeLayer` to that. This way, you can enjoy a variety of different features:

- you can enjoy `UIView` block-based animation;
- you can use `center` to move it around so that when you move its `center` to the `center` of its superview, it will really be centered (right now, if you move the `position` of the layer to `self.view.center`, it's not really quite centered, as it will be the upper left corner of the blue dot's layer that will be in the center);
- you can use UIKit Dynamics to snap it to location or define other behaviors,
- you can use auto-layout constraints to dictate placement if you want,
- you could define a `UIView` subclass that is `IBDesignable` with this dot as a view so that you could add it on a storyboard and see what it looks like; etc.

Comment: Alternatively, one could set the bounds of the shape layer to be the bounding box of its path.

Answer (score -1):

You set the `toValue` in the coordinates system of the superview of `view` (because of using `center` property). Looks like this should work:

```
CABasicAnimation *move = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
move.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(blueDot.position.x, blueDot.position.y)];
move.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds))];
move.duration = 1.0;
[blueDot addAnimation:move forKey:@"myMoveAnimation"];
blueDot.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds));
```

Comment: `CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds)` is the same as `self.view.center.x`. So unfortunately, this produces the same result.